# How to insert data into User model without using django forms?

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I am working on a django project where I can't use django forms, and I'm facing a lot of problem when trying to access the abstract user objects,can anyone please tell me how to access these objects?

and here is my models.py file where I created a custom user so I can register and login using email.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Shahadati_user(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_nID=models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

below the views.py file, and the problem for me that I don't know how to access the first_name, last_name password, etc. objects that are in the abstract user model.

views.py

```
def user_reg(request):
    
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST.get('FirstName')
        last_name = request.POST.get('LastName')
        nID = request.POST.get('nID')
        Email = request.POST.get('em')
        password = request.POST.get('psw')

        ######### the following code case the problem ########
        if password == request.POST.get('pswValidation'):
            hashed_password=make_password(password,None)
            user = Shahadati_user (first_name=first_name,
                                              last_name=last_name,
                                              user_national_id=nID,
                                              email=Email,
                                              password=hashed_password,
                                            )
            
            user.save()

        else:
            raise ValidationError(_("Passwords are not the same !"))
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {'regitered': registered})
```

Comment: Please don't. Use forms. You don't have to use forms to *render* the page, but at least to validate the page...

Comment: can you please give me some resources that help to use forms only for validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd that you have *two* user models. If you make a custom user model. That is the ideal opportunity to add all fields to that model, so make a model like:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    national_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Secondly, it is a common mistake that Django forms need to be rendered in a HTML page. That is *not* the case. Yes, Django forms *can* be rendered in a HTML page, but it is also common to only use these to *validate* the input and then for example create a model object. Django forms remove a lot of boilerplate, and make the validation process robust.

You can define a form for user creation:

```
class CustomUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField()
    password_validation = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'national_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_validation')
        if pwd1 and pwd2 and pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return pwd2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This means that in your HTML form, you simply change the `name="…"` parameters to `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `national_id`, `password` and `password_validation`. But we do *not* have to render that form.

In the view we then thus work with:

```
def user_reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
        else:
            # there is an error in the form
            pass
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {})
```

The form thus will check if all required fields are present, that the passwords match, and will set the password.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was super useful, but can I ask you? you said its odd to make two user models, but the case of my website requires two types of users who have a very different functionalities, you can think about it as delivery apps that contains customers and drivers, So how can I register the other users? create a new django app for them with a new custom user model?

Comment: @DaniaAlhajhassan: so a perso can not be both? Often it turns out people can be at both sides, while perhaps uncommon, after a while people can take multiple tasks in applications. So it is better to work with "roles" (groups). Django already groups, and one can add permissions to these groups?

Comment: no a person can't be both, also they don't have the same objects(attributes), the other user don't have a national id for example. how can I deal with that ? and I'll read more about groups.